# R - transition function for modelling surface water flow with gdistance

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, r-raster, r-sp

I am trying to model overland (surface) water flow from specified origin points to a single downslope goal point using the `gdistance` `shortestPath` function. I need help with defining the appropriate `transitionFunction` for this, as I need to make sure the least cost path only allows water to flow along the path to elevation cells of equal or lesser value than the previous cell. The `transitionFunction` in the example below selects the minimum elevation cell but, based on the `transitionFunction` I have defined, this value may still be greater than the previous cell value.

I realize that, when the above is defined as I want it, the path may terminate before reaching the goal point. This is fine, although I would ideally like to be able to preserve the path from the origin to wherever it terminates if possible.

Also, if anyone knows of a different R package capable of modelling this kind of thing, please let me know.

```
library(gdistance)
library(raster)
library(elevatr)
library(sp)

#load example DEM raster
data(lake)
elevation <- get_elev_raster(lake, z = 9)
#remove negative elevation values from raster
elevation[elevation < 0] <- NA

#create origin and goal points with same projection as elevation raster
origin <- SpatialPoints(cbind(1790000, 640000), proj4string = CRS("+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
goal <- SpatialPoints(cbind(1820000, 540000), proj4string = CRS("+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"))

#create df data and convert to SpatialPointsDataFrame
odf <- data.frame("flowreg" = 1)
gdf <- data.frame("flowreg" = 2)
origindf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(origin, odf)
goaldf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(goal, gdf)
trCost1 <- transition(elevation, transitionFunction=function(x) 1/min(x), directions=8)
trCost1gc <- geoCorrection(trCost1, type="c")

plot(raster(trCost1))   
sPath1 <- shortestPath(trCost1, origin, goal, 
output="SpatialLines")

plot(elevation)
plot(origindf, add = TRUE, col='red', cex = 5)
plot(goaldf, add = TRUE, col='green', cex = 5)
lines(sPath1)
```

[image: resulting <code>shortestPath</code> output]

Comment: Is your current code not preserving the path from the origin to wherever it terminates? I can't tell from your figure.

Comment: The current code is preserving the path, yes. The problem is that the transitionFunction allows the path to flow 'uphill' (i.e., to higher-elevation cells than the centre cell). I want to make the path flow as surface water would flow downslope. Let me know if you have any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the GRASS GIS (accessed in R using `rgrass7`) r.drain function OR `raster::flowPath` achieve what I am trying to do in the above question.